# Scala/Akka Syntax

Tags: scala, akka

I'm new to both Scala and Akka and have been following [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.4/scala/actors.html#Props) tutorial. I came across the following and wondering what exactly this syntax does/mean?

```
import akka.actor.Props

val props1 = Props[MyActor] //Not sure what this means???
val props2 = Props(new ActorWithArgs("arg")) // careful, see below
val props3 = Props(classOf[ActorWithArgs], "arg")
```

I'm not sure what the line commented with `//Not sure what this means` does? It seems like a generic trait that gives a parameterised type. If I look at the [source code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Props.scala), `akka.actor.Props` is defined as an `Object` that extends the [trait](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/AbstractProps.scala) `AbstractProps`. However, AbstractProps is not defined with a type parameter i.e. `AbstractProps[T]`. Can someone explain how that above line works and what it does?

Comment: Also, beware of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042105/differences-between-propsnew-a-with-b-and-propsa-with-b when using `Props[A]` variant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Scala, any object which implements an `apply` method can be called without the `new` keyword, simply by calling `MyObject()`, which will automatically lookup for it's `apply`.

If you look at the [companion object](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html) for [`Props`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Props.scala#L62), you'll see the following method defined:

```
/**
 * Scala API: Returns a Props that has default values except for "creator"
 * which will be a function that creates an instance
 * of the supplied type using the default constructor.
 */
def apply[T <: Actor: ClassTag](): Props = 
    apply(defaultDeploy, implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass, List.empty)
```

This `apply` takes one type parameter and no arguments. `T <: Actor` means that `T`, the type you're passing, must extend `Actor`. That's how Scala knows how to create the object.

Additionally, any method with arity-0 in Scala may drop it's parenthesis. That's how you're seeing `Props[MyActor]` actually compile, as it is equivalent of `Props[MyActor]()`, which is equivalent to `Props.apply[MyActor]()`.

Answer (score 3):

> akka.actor.Props is defined as an Object that extends the trait
>   AbstractProps

Its also defined as a case class:

```
final case class Props(deploy: Deploy, clazz: Class[_], args: immutable.Seq[Any])
```

This is a common pattern in Scala, a class with a companion object. The companion object frequently houses factory methods, and thats what your actually calling in your example.

```
val props1 = Props[MyActor]
```

This simply calls apply() of the companion object. You can omit the parentheses in Scala if no arguments are neccessary and `apply` is a special method that can be invoked directly on the object/instance. Say you have a sequence and want the element at index 1:

```
val s = Seq("one", "two", "three")
// These two are equivalent
s(1) // -> "two"
s.apply(1) // -> "two"
```

Ultimately your code can be rewritten as

```
val props1 = Props.apply[MyActor]()
```